# Mouse single click problems after QGIS install

Tags: qgis, installation

Has anyone had an issue with their single click becoming a double click after installing QGIS on Dell machines?

On two Dell workstations I have installed QGIS and on both my mouse has a tendency to act as a double click unless I hold down on the left button much longer than normally required.

I have adjusted the mouse click settings with no affect.

I have narrowed it down to QGIS and it does not get resolved until I do a total clean install of Windows. Removing QGIS from the machine does not remedy the issue--only a clean install of the OS works. The issue affects all mouse clicking in all programs to include file explorer.

I run a Windows 10 Home 64 bit Dell Inspiron 3847 i7-4790 @ 3.60ghz w/16GB ram. I have tried switching to a mouse with its own driver trying to over ride QGIS and doing a pure windows 10 install with no Dell components.

This issue does not occur on my Toshiba laptop.